# What is the definition of "Worship" according to Islam?

Tags: allah, ibadah

We are to worship Allah and Him alone. 
But what is the definition of worship according to Islam? What does worshiping Allah alone mean?

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate, as from a fiqh perspective worship is prayer and what ever falls under deeds we do to follow Allah's orders and refrain from his prohibitions. When it comes to theology the term might be taken differently. As you may worship Allah, but commit shirk nevertheless.

Comment: @Medi1Saif  I wanted to elaborate more, but my confusion and ignorance on the matter didn't allow me to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Everything that is done for the sake of Allah is worship...
Namaz (prayers)... Helping a poor... Listening and being obedient to your parents.... Lowering your gaze when infront of women other than your sisters... Not to drink alcohol or commit adultery.... Things like this

And worship God alone means, when you pray, do not commit shirk.

Comment: "When you pray, do not commit shirk" What does this mean? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I meant, do not take also other gods in worship, while you pray, you do not do this, you only take in worship Allah. Do you understand now?

Comment: Which other gods can they be? I do not get it. If a person is Muslim, there is only one god already.